# Retrieving more than one records from database

Tags: php, sql

In my database 'coordinates' there are four columns
id
bus_id
latitude
longitude
where a user having a particular bus_is send its long, lat on a regular interval of time. I want to retrieve most updated value for each user. 
Here is my code:

```
<?php
      define('HOST','localhost');
      define('USER','root');
      define('PASS','1234');
      define('DB','coordinates');
      $con = mysqli_connect(HOST,USER,PASS,DB);


     $arr=[];
      for($x=1; $x=3; $x++){
      $query = "SELECT id, longitude, latitude FROM data WHERE bus_id= ".$x." ORDER BY id DESC limit 1 offset 1 " ;
      $qry_result = mysqli_query($con,$query);// or die(mysqli_error());
      }   
       // Insert a new row in the table for each person returned
       while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($qry_result)) {

         array_push($arr, [
           'lat'=>['$latitude'],
           'lng'=>['$longitude'],
           //'recs'=>$recs
         ]);
       }

$record= json_encode($arr);
echo $arr;    
?>
```

when i run this code it doesn't give me right output. Please tell me where am i wrong.

Comment: SELECT id, longitude, latitude FROM data WHERE bus_id= ".$x." ORDER BY id DESC limit 1 offset 1 ---- limit 1 select only first record , remove it , and try again

Comment: what u expect, using LIMIT 1 in query..

Comment: i want to select the most recent values of long, lat of a particular user

Comment: @devpro please help me

Comment: what is user?? is your ID is a user?? or BUS_ID is a user?? did u checked my suggested code?

Comment: yeah i checked but problem still exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should run the while into the for loop. Try this code :

```
    <?php
      define('HOST','localhost');
      define('USER','root');
      define('PASS','123456');
      define('DB','test');
      $con = mysqli_connect(HOST,USER,PASS,DB);

     $arr=[];
      for($x=1; $x<=3; $x++){
       $query = "SELECT id, longitude, latitude FROM data WHERE bus_id= ".$x." ORDER BY id DESC limit 1" ;

      $qry_result = mysqli_query($con,$query);// or die(mysqli_error());
    // Insert a new row in the table for each person returned
       while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($qry_result)) {

         array_push($arr, [
           'lat'=>[$row['latitude']],
           'lng'=>[$row['longitude']],
           //'recs'=>$recs
         ]);
       }
      }   


$record= json_encode($arr);
echo $record;    
?>
```

Comment: Thanks I missed it.. :)

Comment: it is giving me this error:
Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in C:\xampp\htdocs\map_code\js.php on line 10

Answer (score 0):

use :

```
$query = "SELECT id, longitude, latitude FROM data WHERE bus_id= ".$x." ORDER BY id DESC" ;
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all change your query and remove LIMIT from statement as:

```
$query = "
SELECT id, longitude, latitude
FROM DATA
WHERE bus_id= ".$x."
ORDER BY id DESC";
```

Second, you need to get most updated value for each user as:

```
$arr = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($qry_result)) {
    $arr[$row['id']]['lat'] = $row['latitude'];
    $arr[$row['id']]['lng'] = $row['longitude'];
}
$record= json_encode($arr);
echo $record;
```

**Issues:**

1. You are expecting multiple data but using LIMIT 1
2. I don't know how its work in array_push `'lat'=>['$latitude'],`. Here what is `$latitude`?
3. You are echoing `$arr` instead of `$result` after `json_encode` function.

**Side Note:**

Always use error reporting in your code for getting all errors.

Comment: latitude is a column in table in my db

Comment: sorry i couldn't understand you last comment

Comment: @hibaali: i am assuming u r getting the array as like that: Array ( [0] => Array ( [lat] => Array ( [0] => **$lan** ) [lng] => Array ( [0] => **$lat** ) )